# Is the dependency between 2 random variables always symmetric?

Tags: random-variables, independence

If you have 2 random variables, $X$ and $Y$, is the dependency symmetric? In other words, if $Y$ depends on $X$, is $X$ dependent on $Y$? If not, what is a counter example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Standard textbooks usually define independence between pairs of random variables, and less of it as a "directed" relationship.

It might be helpful look at it using conditional probability. (I'm using discrete random variables for simplicity.) For any two r.v.s $X$ and $Y$,

$p(X,Y) = p(X) p(Y|X) = p(Y)p(X|Y)$

Here, you can say that $Y$ depends on $X$ if $p(Y|X) \ne p(Y)$, and vice versa. Note that if $p(Y|X) \ne p(Y)$, then $p(X|Y)$ cannot be equal to $p(X)$. (Consider what happens otherwise.) In this sense, if $Y$ depends on $X$, then $X$ depends on $Y$. The converse is also true.

Comment: Thanks. That equation really helps. But it's kind of not intuitive to me how this applies to some situations. For example, say $X$ represents the amount of money I have today, and $Y$ represents the amount of money I have tomorrow. Then it's clear that $Y$ depends on $X$, but why should $X$ be independent on $Y$, which seems to be implying that my current amount of money depends on how much money I have in the future?

Comment: Yes. Think of it this way. Consider $X$ be the amount of money you have today, and let $p(X)$ be its distribution. Similarly, let $Y$ be the amount of money you have tomorrow with distribution $p(Y)$. If I know that you have $Y=10^6$ dollars, then the distribution of $X$ given $Y$ will be skewed towards high values. (Assuming no one earns a million dollars overnight.) Compare that with a scenario when I don't know how much you have tomorrow and I need to guess how much money you have today.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I suppose this is just Bayesian inference, using the future to update a hypothesis from the past.